# When i click save button label display successfully done but after few second that label should be disappear

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0

I'm try to hide the label after few second but it is updating page continuously after 10sec, 
i just want it once time when i click save button label on display me successfully for 10sec and get disappear

```
protected void LinkBtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblWriteTest.Text = "";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "HideLabel", 
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">setTimeout(\"document.getElementById('" +
    lblWriteTest.ClientID + "').style.display='none'\",10000)</script>");
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest using jQuery and AJAX calls to do things like this. You get very robust plugins like jGrowl for this kind of "notification" bubbles.

Comment: i have no idea how to use jQuery and AJAX

Comment: try using a timer. Set the label text. wait for 10 seconds and set visibility of label to false. then set timer.enabled to false.

Comment: @Mano Then it's not too late to learn :) This sort of client script registering clog up the code behind when they should typically be run on the client side. To give this notification you will at the very least (using AJAX) cause a post-back or worse a full page reload. Much better to get started with jQuery and AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

add this code on page load

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "HideLabel", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">function hide(){setTimeout(\"document.getElementById('" + lbl.ClientID + "').style.display='none'\",300)}</script>");
    btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return hide()");
```

i hope this will help you.

Comment: it is also doing same thing and i want to do that on button event

Comment: sorry it is doing again same thing

Comment: from this code impossible may be you are using other functions which post back automatically after 10 sec. review you code again.